# Shinydashboard: 'restoreInput' is not an exported object from 'namespace:shiny'

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I am using RStudio to create a new Shiny app. I copy and paste the code sample from https://rdrr.io/cran/shinydashboard/man/renderValueBox.html into the app.R. I receive this error:

```
Warning: Error in : 'restoreInput' is not an exported object from 'namespace:shiny'
Stack trace (innermost first):
    45: getExportedValue
    44: ::
    43: dashboardSidebar
    42: inherits
    41: tagAssert
    40: dashboardPage
     1: runApp
Error : 'restoreInput' is not an exported object from 'namespace:shiny'
```

Here is my sessionInfo() output:

```
R version 3.3.3 (2017-03-06)
Platform: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Fedora 25 (Workstation Edition)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8       
 [4] LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C              
[10] LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] shiny_0.13.0         shinydashboard_0.6.0 dplyr_0.5.0          readr_1.0.0         

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.3      digest_0.6.9     assertthat_0.1   mime_0.4         grid_3.3.3      
 [6] plyr_1.8.4       R6_2.1.2         jsonlite_0.9.19  xtable_1.8-0     gtable_0.2.0    
[11] DBI_0.5-1        magrittr_1.5     scales_0.4.1     ggplot2_2.2.1    lazyeval_0.2.0  
[16] tools_3.3.3      munsell_0.4.3    httpuv_1.3.3     colorspace_1.3-2 htmltools_0.3.5 
[21] tibble_1.2
```

UPDATE:
1) I tried the sample from a different machine and produced the same error.
2) I also took a shinydashboard skeleton app and reproduced this error.

Comment: I ran the code and it worked. My R version is `3.4.0`.  `shinydashboard_0.6.1`, and `shiny_1.0.3`.

Comment: Did you run the `Example` code that starts `if (interactive()) {`? It worked for me too. Not sure why you're getting an error...

Comment: I ran update.packages() and the newer versions of shiny and shinydashboard work. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ran update.packages() and newer versions didn't have this issue.

Comment: Specifically you only need to update the `shiny` package. You should mark this as the solution.