# Error on shiny server ERROR: 'restoreInput' is not an exported object from 'namespace:shiny'

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, shinydashboard

I'm trying to run a shiny app that works perfectly well when I run it locally but not when I try and run it on a shiny web server. When I try and access it through the browser all I get is the following error message:

```
ERROR: 'restoreInput' is not an exported object from 'namespace:shiny'
```

I'm aware that a question regarding this error message has previously been asked here: [Shinydashboard: 'restoreInput' is not an exported object from 'namespace:shiny'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44614517/shinydashboard-restoreinput-is-not-an-exported-object-from-namespaceshiny) but I believe that person was running the app locally so my question is distinct from their's. Nevertheless I have obviously tried to implement all of the solutions provided for that answer which are basically just "ensure you have the latest version of R and the latest version of the required packages". I've done this and when I ssh into the shiny server and source my ui and server scripts and then call `sessionInfo()` this is the output:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /usr/lib/libblas/libblas.so.3.6.0
LAPACK: /usr/lib/lapack/liblapack.so.3.6.0

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_GB.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C
 [3] LC_TIME=en_GB.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_GB.UTF-8
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_GB.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_GB.UTF-8
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_GB.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_GB.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

other attached packages:
[1] shinydashboard_0.6.1 shinythemes_1.1.1    ggplot2_2.2.1
[4] raster_2.6-7         sp_1.2-7             leaflet_1.1.0
[7] shiny_1.0.5

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.15     magrittr_1.5     munsell_0.4.3    colorspace_1.3-2
 [5] xtable_1.8-2     lattice_0.20-35  R6_2.2.2         rlang_0.2.0
 [9] plyr_1.8.4       grid_3.4.3       gtable_0.2.0     htmltools_0.3.6
[13] crosstalk_1.0.0  yaml_2.1.17      lazyeval_0.2.1   digest_0.6.15
[17] tibble_1.4.2     htmlwidgets_1.0  mime_0.5         compiler_3.4.3
[21] pillar_1.2.1     scales_0.5.0     httpuv_1.3.6.1
```

which is almost identical to the output I get when I call `sessionInfo()` in my local version of R in which the app runs seamlessly. See below:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United Kingdom.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United Kingdom.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                           
[5] LC_TIME=English_United Kingdom.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] shinydashboard_0.6.1 shinythemes_1.1.1    ggplot2_2.2.1        raster_2.6-7        
[5] sp_1.2-6             leaflet_1.1.0        shiny_1.0.5         

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.14     magrittr_1.5     munsell_0.4.3    colorspace_1.3-2 xtable_1.8-2    
 [6] lattice_0.20-35  R6_2.2.2         rlang_0.1.2      plyr_1.8.4       tools_3.4.3     
[11] rgdal_1.2-16     grid_3.4.3       gtable_0.2.0     rgeos_0.3-26     htmltools_0.3.6 
[16] crosstalk_1.0.0  yaml_2.1.14      lazyeval_0.2.1   digest_0.6.14    tibble_1.3.4    
[21] htmlwidgets_0.9  rsconnect_0.8.5  mime_0.5         compiler_3.4.3   scales_0.5.0    
[26] jsonlite_1.5     httpuv_1.3.5
```

What's particularly strange is that initially when I ssh-ed into the shiny server and sourced the ui.R file I was getting this same error message. After updating R and all the packages this doesn't happen anymore but I still get the same error when I try and open the app in the browser. I added the following lines to the start of both my server and ui scripts to ensure that it was using the correct version of R and the up-to-date packages.

```
loc <- '/path/to/location/of/correct/r/packages'
.libPaths(c(loc, .libPaths()))
```

Can anybody advise me as to what might be going on or how best to troubleshoot?

Comment: Try deleting the package and reinstalling as superuser

Comment: Which package? shiny or shinydashboard? (I'm fairly certain that one of these two is where the problem lies)